# java.util.logging FileHandler world readable permissions

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging, filehandler

How to specify the readable by everyone permission on which data is being written by `java.util.logging.FileHandler`

I want to give 755 kind of permission, so that other unix groups can also read these log files.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code converts the permission of an existing file to a full permission 0777:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;

public class testFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        String dir= "path to your file/test.txt";  
        Path path = Paths.get(dir);
        try {
            // permission 0777 
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am asking while we flush data using FileHandler, not after the file is created.

Comment: Would you please share your code, so I can see how I can be more helpful